# XUnit: Passing a multidimensional array as class data

Tags: resharper, xunit, data-driven-tests

I've created a class that is used as `ClassData` to a Xunit test method marked with `Theory` attribute.

I am getting a following error message

[image]

I was checking other StackOverflow answers regarding this but I am not sure what could possibly wrong.

I am sure that I am wrapping `new [,] {...}` and `1` within `new object[]{...}`, which is what should be returned to the `ClassData` attribute.

Would someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Could it possibly a bug in ReSharper Xunit test runner (R# version used is 2016.2)?

**Test Class**

```
public class Chapter1_8Test : BaseTest
{
    private readonly Chapter1_8 _sut = new Chapter1_8();

    public Chapter1_8Test(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
    {
    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(Chapter1_8Data))]
    public void TestGettingZeroPositions(int[,] matrix, int expected)
    {
        _output.WriteLine(matrix.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Class Data**

```
public class Chapter1_8Data : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    private readonly List<object[]> _data = new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[]
        {
            new[,] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } },
            1
        }
    };

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you run the test from command line?